# How to get the number of results in an App Engine query before actually iterating through them all

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

In my Google App Engine app I need to fetch and return a potentially large number of entities from a datastore query in response to a service call GET request. This call may return potentially thousands of entities and MBs of serialized data.

The first portion of the response packet communicates how many entities are in the serialized results, followed by all of the serialized entities. Currently I am iterating through all the entities in the query with a [`QueryResultIterator`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/QueryResultIterator) up to a maximum page size limit, after which I return a cursor from which can be used to continue fetching where the previous call left off (if the maximum was reached and there are still results in the query). As I iterate through the results, I save them in a list. Once I've either exhausted the query results or reached the maximum page size, I can then get the number of entities from the size of this list. But then I have to iterate through this list again to serialize each of the entities and write the results to the response output stream.

I don't know that this is the most efficient method to perform this operation. Is there a way I can get the number of entities in a query's results before actually iterating through them all or fetching them directly into a list? (The list method doesn't work anyway because I'm using cursors, which requires the use of QueryResultIterator).

`QueryResultIterator` has a method [`getIndexList()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/QueryResultIterator#getIndexList%28%29). Would this be a less costly way to get the number of entities in the query's results? I'm assuming this list would contain exactly one index object for each entity in the query's results. Also, I'd need this list to only contain the indexes for the entities after the current cursor position for the interator. Is my understanding correct or would this method not do what I think it would?

A list of just indexes would require much less memory than loading a list of whole entities. Although, I don't know if this list would be limited at all by the query's prefetch or chunk sizes, or if I'd want to use the query's limit parameter at all because I would only be interested in knowing how many entities were in the results up to the maximum page size plus one (to know there are still more results and provide a cursor to continue).

Currently I'm setting the prefetch and chunk size (to the size of my page limit), but I'm not using the limit or offset parameters since I'm using cursors instead. From what I understand cursors are preferable to offset/limit. Would setting the limit parameter affect continuing a query with a cursor?

Clearly I have quite a few questions as to how GAE datastore queries work and how they're affected by changing parameters. So any insights are appreciated. The documentation for App Engine APIs is often sparse, as in one sentence descriptions of methods stating pretty much what can be deduced from the method signature. They don't generally go into much detail otherwise. Maybe the way I'm doing it currently is just fine after all. It works as is, but I'm trying to optimize the service call to get the best response time possible for my client application.

**UPDATE:** By the way, I am using [Objectify](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) v3 in my app and to perform this query. There are several places I am required to use the low-level datastore API, including to do geo-location queries (with [geomodel](https://code.google.com/p/javageomodel/)) and projection queries (which aren't support in Objectify v3). So if there is a good way to do this using Objectify, that would be ideal. Otherwise I can use the low-level API, but it's always messier this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the low-level api and Objectify have a count() method (look at the javadocs for details). However, counting can be a very expensive and lengthy operation - it costs 1 small op for every number returned. For example, count() returning 5000 costs 5000 small ops (plus 1 read for the query), and takes as long as it would take to do a keys-only scan of all 5000 (which is what GAE actually does).

If you absolutely must have an exact count, you probably need to aggregate this value yourself by incrementing/decrementing a (possibly sharded) counter. This gets very tricky when you are dealing with filtered queries.

There is no one right solution here. Google searches give you totals like "About 119,000,000 results" which are deliberately inexact and almost certainly precalculated. For smaller result sets, using count() can be acceptable - but you might want to apply a limit() so that you never break the bank. You can always say "More than 500 results..."

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info. Seems maybe the best route is to populate a list in memory with the query results, up to a maximum size limit. Then get the count from the list and iterate through it to serialize the entities in the service call response. I was hoping to avoid the large memory usage required to contain all the response entities in a list, but the size should still be within reason on an F1 instance (no more than 20-30MB). I was also hoping to only iterate through them once, but this requires 2 passes. Other ways require more datastore ops and wouldn't necessarily be faster though.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to fetch no of record than you can use following code

```
  com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query qry = new com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query("EntityName");
  com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
  int totalCount = datastoreService.prepare(qry).countEntities(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```

anf if you want filter than you can used

```
qry.addFilter("firstName", FilterOperator.EQUAL, firstName);
```

i hope it will help you

Comment: I am using Objectify to create my queries. I probably should have noted this in the question. Is it possible to do something similar with Objectify? I can (and need to in several places) use the low-level API, so this may be the way to go if there isn't a way in Objectify.

Comment: so i think you can use this int q = ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(yourClassName.class).count();